# Which is better option? Create 1 Pandas DataFrame having large size or multiple DataFrames having smaller size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, memory-management

I want to work on millions of data in python. almost (500000 rows * 10 columns)
I am having around 1GB RAM size.
Which one is a better approach for fast performance and minimal memory usage?
Either to go for a single Pandas DataFrame or if I create almost 10000 or 5000 DataFrame containing sub set of records
If we create multiple DataFrames, then how much maximum DataFrame can pandas support for a particular memory size?
Also, please suggest incase there is any other open source data structure which can work better.

I tried creating a DataFrame of 1GB data from a csv file and it took almost 1 min to read the file via pd.read_csv().
I want to perform read and write operations on Pandas DataFrame with high performance and better memory utilization .
Please suggest if I should go with multiple DataFrames (Need to consider the maintainenece of DataFrame aspect also) or any other suggestions.

Comment: As long as you can hold the entire DataFrame in memory at one time, there isn't really a difference. The reason is that any disk operations (load or save to file) will be significantly slower than in-memory operations.

Comment: Splitting a dataframe does not impact performance as long as they are big enough. Pandas introduce a small overhead to compute each dataframe (eg. 10-100 us) and so this overhead will be multiplied by the number of dataframes. Having 10000 dataframe should cause an overhead in the order of a second. The main issue is that this splitting will certainly make your code significantly more complex. If you care about the memory usage, you could consider using Dask which is AFAIK meant to address this problem.

Comment: Sound like you need a database rather than a CSV file. Constantly reading / writing to a CSV give terrible performance. Take a step back from the hardware and tell us what you are trying to do. Do you need everything in the CSV or only a subset in memory? Are you appending or updating the data inside?

Comment: @CodeDifferent : I want to perform read/write operations on DataFrame and not in the CSV file. Loading data from csv will be a 1 time operation. At the time of processing, need to update rows/insert rows in the DataFrame.

Comment: Do you need all the rows inside the DataFrame to perform your operations? What happen to the rows that you add / update in the DataFrame? Don't you want to write them back to disk? Also, that 1GB CSV may be half or a third of its size as a SQLite DB.

Comment: I will be needing specific rows from the Dataframe. I again tried .loc() operation with "5000000 rows * 14 columns". It took around 70-100ms. Similar operation I tried with multiple DataFrames having size of "100000 * 4", it took 15-20ms. But if we have to choose, which option should be more feasible if the priority is best performance and best memory management.

Comment: AFAIK the cost of 1 `loc` is independent of the number of rows but it may be a bit slower with more columns. Note that using `loc` is generally discouraged if you want to read all the rows or even a lot of them (it is *very* slow for that). Besides this, you could read/store your input file using a more efficient file format.